# How to save Radio group and toggle input data into database?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

Html

```
<div class="grid-child purple">
 <lightning-layout vertical-align="start" class="general-form-layout" multiple-rows="true">
 <lightning-record-edit-form
  object-api-name="Expo_Scenario__c"
  record-id={recordId}
  density="comfy"
  onsuccess={handleSuccess}
  onload={handleOnLoad}
  onsubmit={handleSubmit}
  onerror={handleError}>
  <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
     <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-input-field field-name={ExpoName}></lightning-input-field>
     </div>
     <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-input-field field-name={Expoview}></lightning-input-field>
     </div>
     <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning-input-field field-name={ExpoID}></lightning-input-field>
     </div>
  </div>
  <lightning-radio-group name="radioGroup"
     label={label.capaWorkOutsideCanada}
     options={options2}
     value={value}
     type="radio"></lightning-radio-group>
  <lightning-radio-group name="radioGroup"
     label={label.BillRate}
     options={options3}
     value={value}
     type="radio"></lightning-radio-group>
  <lightning-input data-id="toggle1" type="toggle" label="Enable Resources" checked={alertresult} onchange={handleResorceChange}></lightning-input>
  <br/>
  <div class="slds-m-top_large slds-grid slds-grid_align-center slds-align–absolute-center">
     &nbsp;&nbsp;
     <lightning-button  type="submit" variant="brand" label="Save"></lightning-button>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
  </lightning-record-edit-form>
 </lightning-layout>
```

JS

```
import {LightningElement,api,track,wire} from 'lwc';
import {NavigationMixin} from 'lightning/navigation';
import Expo_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Expo_Scenario__c.Name';
import Expo_OPPID from '@salesforce/schema/Expo_Scenario__c.OpportunityID__c';
import Expo_Radiobutton from '@salesforce/schema/Expo_Scenario__c.Radiobutton__c';
import Expo_toggleswap from '@salesforce/schema/Expo_Scenario__c.togglebutton__c';
export default class CorporationForm extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    ExpoName = Expo_NAME;
    ExpoID = Expo_OPPID;


    @track alertresult = true;

    get options2() {
        return [{
                label: 'Yes',
                value: 'option1'
            },
            {
                label: 'No',
                value: 'option2'
            },
        ];
    }
    get options3() {
        return [{
                label: 'Yes',
                value: 'option1'
            },
            {
                label: 'No',
                value: 'option2'
            },
        ];
    }

    handleResorceChange(event) {
        this.alertresult = event.target.checked;
        this.alertresultcheck = true;
        if (event.target.checked === false) {
            this.alertresult = false;
            this.tabAlert = true;
        }
    }
```

From the above code, I am able to map input fields data to record's fields but I need to save the below tags data to the record. there are boolean fields in the object. I need to save the below tags data to those boolean fields.

```
   <lightning-radio-group name="radioGroup"
     label={label.BillRate}
     options={options3}
     value={value}
     type="radio"></lightning-radio-group>
  <lightning-input data-id="toggle1" type="toggle" label="Enable Resources" checked= 
  {alertresult} onchange={handleResorceChange}></lightning-input>
  <br/>
```

Can someone please suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the [record edit form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) component clearly documents how to achieve Overriding Default Behaviors.

in your handleSubmit function, you can gain access to the current field(s) being submitted and assign values to them based on *whatever, such as other input fields in your form

```
    handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault(); // stop the form from submitting
        const fields = event.detail.fields;
        fields.Street = '32 Prince Street';
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
}
```

You are already invoking the function when submitting the form, but have not shared what you have tried, so i'd refer you to the documentation to complete your functionality based on the above..

Comment: Hi glls, Thanks for your response. you have a hardcoded value. can please tell me how to save YES or NO values of radio buttons from UI to True or false and for Toggle input data also. I have imported two boolean fields in the JS. I need to set to those fields from UI while saving

Comment: you can use a tempalte.querySelector, or, idk , add a change handler to your radio buttons, to update a property, and then use that instead of the hardcoded value. You can chose whatever method you want for populating the appropriate field with the value you want.